# Me imprime toString pero con valor 0

Tags: java

Tengo un pequeño problema. En clase diseñe un pequeño programa el cual consta de 3 clases. Punto, Circulo y Prueba. Ya tengo los métodos para cada clase y me imprime los valores excepto uno que es centro atributo de la clase Punto, el cual debe de mostrar cuales son las condenadas de este, todo lo demás que me pidió realizar el programa como área, perímetro y radio me sale bien, pero no me sale lo que es el centro.

**Clase Punto**

```
public class Punto {
    private int X;
    private int Y;

    public Punto(int x, int y){
        this.X = X;
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public int getX() {
        return X;
    }

    public void setX(int X) {
        this.X = X;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return Y;
    }

    public void setY(int Y) {
        this.Y = Y;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "Eje X: " +this.X +"Eje Y: " +this.Y;
    }
}
```

**Clase Círculo**

```
public class Circulo {
    public Punto centro;
    private double radio;
    private double area;
    private double perimetro;

    public Circulo(int radio, int area, int perimetro){
        this.radio = radio;
        this.area = area;
        this.perimetro = perimetro;

    }

    public Punto getCentro() {
        return centro;
    }

    public void setCentro(Punto centro) {
        this.centro = centro;
    }

    public double getRadio() {
        return radio;
    }

    public void setRadio(double x, double y) {

        this.radio = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x, 2)+Math.pow(y, 2));
    }

    public double getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(double area) {
        this.area = Math.PI*Math.pow(this.radio, 2);
    }

    public double getPerimetro() {
        return perimetro;
    }

    public void setPerimetro(double radio) {
        this.perimetro = 2*Math.PI*this.radio;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "El radio es: " +radio +" con un área de: " +area +" y un perímetro de: " +perimetro;
    }


}
```

**Clase Prueba**

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prueba {
    private static Punto punto = new Punto(0,0);
    private static Circulo circulo = new Circulo(0,0,0);
    private static int corX, corY;
    private static double radio;
    private static Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String [] args){
        introducirCordenadas();
        calcularRadio();
        calcularPerimetro();
        calcularArea();
        imprimirDatos();
    }

    public static void introducirCordenadas(){
        System.out.println("A continuación introduzca la cordenada de X");
        corX = entrada.nextInt();
        punto.setX(corX);
        System.out.println("A continuación introduzca la cordenada de Y");
        corY = entrada.nextInt();
        punto.setY(corY);

      circulo.centro = new Punto(corX, corY); 
    }

    public static void calcularRadio(){
        circulo.setRadio(punto.getX(), punto.getY());
    }

    public static void calcularPerimetro(){
        circulo.setPerimetro(circulo.getRadio());
    }

    public static void calcularArea(){
        circulo.setArea(circulo.getRadio());
    }

    public static void imprimirDatos(){
        System.out.println("El centro " +circulo.centro.toString()); //Sale X=0, Y=0
        System.out.println("Los valores son: " +circulo.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Los de corX, y corY, estaba pasando cero para inicializarlo, pero en el transcurso iban a cambiar... Pero ya quedo, el error estaba en la clase Punto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error esta en el constructor de la clase punto, esto debido a que a los atributos de la clase le estas asignando los mismos atributos y no las varias que pasas como parametros

```
public class Punto {
  private int X;
  private int Y;

  public Punto(int x, int y){
    this.X = X; //cambiar por x minuscula
    this.Y = Y; //cambiar por y minuscula
  }
//demas código
```

Aca la clase punto modificada

```
public class Punto {
  private int X;
  private int Y;
  public Punto(int x, int y){
    this.X = x;
    this.Y = y;
  }
  public int getX() {
    return X;
  }
  public void setX(int X) {
    this.X = X;
  }
  public int getY() {
    return Y;
  }
  public void setY(int Y) {
    this.Y = Y;
  }
  public String toString(){
    return "Eje X: " +this.X +"Eje Y: " +this.Y;
  }
}
```

Comment: Listo, muchas gracias, era eso.